# Refresh Shield UI ASP Chart without reloading the page?

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I am using a Shield UI ASP.NET chart on a web page (aspx). I need to refresh the chart and display data according to the selected item from the dropdown. But what happens is that when pressing the button the page reloads, and I need the other charts to remain with their selected series. Here is my code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0) {
            ShieldChart3.DataSource = new List<int>() { 12, 3, 4, 2, 12, 3, 4, 17, 22, 34, 54, 67 };
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            ShieldChart3.DataSource = new List<int>() { 3, 9, 12, 14, 22, 32, 45, 12, 67, 45, 55, 7 };
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            ShieldChart3.DataSource = new List<int>() { 23, 19, 11, 134, 242, 352, 435, 22, 637, 445, 555, 57 };
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            ShieldChart3.DataSource = new List<int>() { 13, 19, 112, 114, 212, 332, 435, 132, 67, 45, 55, 7 };
        }
    }
```

How can I refresh just one of the charts reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a button, but it's code will be handled not from the C# code module, but within the script. In order to do so you need to declare a JS function. See the code:

```
    function PS(qtr){
        var SD = SalesData[qtr].values;
        detailChartElement = $('#' + "<%=ShieldChart3.ClientID%>"),
        detailChart = detailChartElement.swidget(),
        initialOptions = detailChart.initialOptions,
        headerText = ' Your sales data... ';
        detailChart.destroy();
        detailChartElement.shieldChart($.extend(initialOptions, {
            primaryHeader: {
                text: headerText

            },
            dataSeries: [{
                seriesType: 'line',
                collectionAlias: 'Sales data...',
                data: SD
            }]
        }));
    }
```

than, in the button's click event you should place a clal to the function. Or eve more simply you can use a select to pass tha value to the function:

```
<select id="Quarter" onChange="PS(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value="2">Option 3</option>
    <option value="3">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the chart control inside [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control and make this button UpdatePanel's trigger. This way when you click it - page will perform only partial postback and only chart inside of UpdatePanel will be refreshed on button click.